# Correct use of continue in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I have always believed you use **continue** as follows:

```
var i;

for (i = 0;  i < 10; i++) {
  if(i%2===0) {
    continue;
  }
}
```

Or

```
var i, myloop;

myloop: for (i = 0;  i < 10; i++) {
  if(i%2===0) {
    continue myloop;
  }
}
```

But when I run these two snippets of code through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/), I get the error:

```
Problem at line 5 character 5: Unexpected 'continue'.
     continue;
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct usage?

Comment: You had to move the `var i` up to even get that far, right? Improving your code is JSLint's secondary concern, enforcing Doug Crockford's personal opinions about JavaScript being its first. There's always [JSHint](http://anton.kovalyov.net/2011/02/20/why-i-forked-jslint-to-jshint/) if you want a less opinionated alternative.

Comment: Yes. JSHint. JSLint is far too dogmatic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess [JSLint just hates `continue`](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/jslint_com/message/2052):

> There are almost always better ways of writing
>   statements that more explicitly define what you are attempting to do without
>   resorting to continue. JSLint is all about the good parts, and not about the
>   parts that are acceptable. It forces you to use a higher standard than the one
>   defined.
>
> Douglas says it best in his book:
>
> "The continue statement jumps to the top of the loop. I have never seen a piece
>   of code that was not improved by refactoring it to remove the continue
>   statement."

Comment: That's so stupid though. 'continue' makes it easy to 'exit early' in a loop. I guess the inner loop can be placed in an external function, to keep readability, but that's not always handy.

Comment: @Evert: You must be confusing continue with break (which does what you say and which is not frown upon by Crockford).

Comment: No, sorry.. say you want to loop an array but only do something with certain elements in that array. I can do if (!condition) continue; at the top of the loop, or if (condition) { .. }  stuff. The former has the advantage that there's one less level of nesting.

Comment: @Evert: I see, now I understand your wording ('exit early in a loop' had confused me). As concerns the question of continue vs. nesting, the point is that having that extra level of nesting is a Good Thing, since it gives a clear visual clue that the code applies only when the condition is satisfied. (Personally, I'm not sure whether I agree more with Crockford or with you, but I'd definitely not call it 'so stupid'.)

Comment: Fair enough; There are other things I disagree with crockford with; core object overloading .. ugh.

Comment: I've never understood what's so hard to read about continue. The second you've established you no longer need to do anything else on a given iteration there's no reason not to use it.

Answer (score 3):

You must tick "Tolerate continue", [Crockford doesn't like it](https://www.crockford.com/code.html#continue%20statement).

Answer (score 0):

There is an option at the bottom of JSlint that says

Tolerate continue

maybe it has issues with it?

Answer (score 0):

JSLint doesn't like `continue` because Douglas doesn't like it.

`continue` skips to the next iteration. If you don't insert it, the code will carry on executing. If you want to exit the loop, use `break`.

Answer (score 0):

This was good enough for me.
`// eslint-disable-next-line no-continue`